# Embedding like page action with post on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When we post a feed on Facebook using Graph API, a parameter is passed called "Action" in which we need to pass an array of actions which contains name of action and link.

```
$feed=array(
'message' => "Trial fb post",
    'name' => "trial",
    'caption' => "Trial caption",
    'actions' => array(
        array(
        'name' => 'Give it a try',
            'link' => 'http://www.blinkpot.com/'
            )
    )
    );
```

I saw some posts having like this page option by which users can like the respective page. 
How can I attach that action with my post.